# SignalR chat application issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, xmpp, signalr, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing SignalR chat applications and got stuck with some performance related issues. I have simple basic problem, but I don't know how to resolve this particular issue.

**Problem**

When user sends message to other user who is not online at that time.So, how do I track unsent messages.

**Possible Solution 1**

Insert all messages in database with bit field representing its sent status.

**Issue:**
The database size will grow as messages increase, so querying unsent messages will take more time.

**Possible Solution 2**

Insert unseen messages into some temporary database. When the message is sent, delete that message.

**Issue:**
Here we are searching and deleting the messages. So, more concurrency, more issues.

These solutions might be feasible for lesser users.
I heard that it can be done through **Google Cloud Messaging** . I want some constructive solution, not some third party configuration.

Any help would be appreciated, either conceptually or technologically.

Comment: What would be the average number of messages and the size of a message?

Comment: We are targeting a whatsapp like traffic.

Comment: Event sourcing would work nicely here